# checking array if has same value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, filter

Learning by coding, here i have an array of objects (data), and nodeId which is number , i want to check if that arrays 'target' has same value as nodeId then 'return', should i use map(), find(), filter(), how should i know which to use ?
english is not my mother language so could be mistakes

data:

```js
  const Test = '7'
const nodeId = parseInt(Test);

  
  const data = [
    { target: 4, name: "usa" },
    { target: 7, name: "England" },
    { target: 3, name: "Japan" }
  ];
  
  
   if (check if data and nodeId both have same value then) {
    return;
  }
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: *"then 'return'"*: and else? Also, `return` is only valid inside a function... And if you `return`, you might want to pass some *result* to the caller of that function (what should the result be?)

Comment: What are you returning (from your imaginary function)? Is it the object in the array that matches the `nodeId`, or do you just want to return `true` if it finds a match?

Comment: if it find a match could return true or false

Comment: do you mind at least trying it first? you can read the docs on [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to see which one to use. Then if something is wrong we can help debug

Comment: [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is the method you need. It will shortcut when it finds a match and returns a boolean. `return arr.some(obj => obj.target === nodeId)`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you have done into the problem and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is probably what you want to use

```
const check = data.some((elem) => elem.target === nodeId) 
console.log(check) // true if exist or false if it doesnt
if(check) {
  // reached if it exist
}
```

check would be `false` if it doesn't exist or `true` if it does. It will stop running once it finds a match whereas [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would run the entire array. If you also want to get the element then you should use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but i'm going to try and answer it as easily as possible.

> should i use map(), find(), filter(), how should i know which to use ?

That depends on what your hypothetical function or code would require, for example if you want the item that matched your value, then you would use `.find()` because it returns single value based on a condition.

similarly if you wish to return an array based on items that match the conditions, you would use `.filter()`, and same if you just want to check if your value exists in the array, you could use `.some` or `.every`.

in your code example, I'm assuming you want to return the specific value that matched with your nodeId, with that assumption, here's how that will work

```js
function getDataBasedOnNodeId (dataObjects, matchValue) { 
 return dataObjects.find(item => item.target === Number(matchValue))
}

const data = [
    { target: 4, name: "usa" },
    { target: 7, name: "England" },
    { target: 3, name: "Japan" }
];
  

return getDataBasedOnNodeId(data, 7)
```